# How can I put colors in console output with Robot Framework

Tags: colors, robotframework

I would like to put some colors in the console output of RobotFramework.

I tried to use the console color codes like:

```
${message}=  Set Variable  hello world!
Log To Console  \\e[0;36;49m${message}\\e[0;39;49m
```

(In a linux console, `echo -e "\e[0;36;49mHello world!\e[0;39;49m"` print `Hello world!` in cyan)

(I also tried with one `\` and also `\033[31m, \033[0m, ...` codes)

But it doesn't work...

So, is it possible to do something like:

```
${message}=  Set Variable  hello world!
Log To Console ${message.red}
```

I found [this module](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.org/en/3.0/_modules/robot/output/console/highlighting.html) but I didn't found anything on how to use it :(

I tried:

```
Log To Console ${message.red}  robot.output.console.highlighting
```

and

```
${message}=  Evaluate  ${message}.red  robot.output.console.highlighting
Log To Console ${message}
```

But none works :'(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because of Robot Framework interpretation of '\', `Log To Console  \\033[31mRed Text\\033[0m` doesn't color the output.

To solve this problem, you have to `Evaluate` the variable before to log in to console:

```
${message}=  Evaluate  "\\033[31mRed Text\\033[0m"
Log To Console  ${message}
```

---

I ended up with the below solution, which I find quite "clean":

```
*** Variables ***
${BLACK}  "\\033[30m"
${RED}    "\\033[31m"
# More colors ANSI codes...

*** Keywords ***
Initialize Colors
  ${black}=  Evaluate  ${BLACK}
  Set Test Variable  ${black}
  ${red}=  Evaluate  ${RED}
  Set Test Variable  ${red}
  # More colors...
```

Then, you just have to use the previous keyword in a Suite/Test Case Setup and you can colorize your outputs like below:

```
Log To Console  ${cyan}Some Text in cyan and a ${red}${variable}${cyan} in red${default}
```

Comment: I get: Creating keyword 'Set Test Variable' failed: Keyword with same name defined multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

can I ask your overall goal here?  Is it just to output random text in different colours?

Here's what I do to easily signal PASS/FAIL etc on different test cases to make them stand out:

```
--monitorcolors ansi
```

In your command to run your test suite, include the above toward the beginning of the command.

Comment: I don't have the option --monitorcolors but I have --consolecolors which seems to be the corresponding option. This didn't solve my problem: it affects the "PASS"/"FAIL" color enabling but doesn't affect the other output colors.

Comment: glad you were able to solve your issue, apologies my answer was wide of the mark, I made the assumption you were looking to colour PASS/FAIL and qualified it to be clear

Comment: Your comment make me ask myself the right questions which put me on the road of my answer, so a big thanks though ;-)