# How to print log to console in different color in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I need print text in different color on console

```
*** Variables ***
${DATE}    2011-06-27
${status}    Babitha
${BLACK}  "\\033[30m"
${RED}    "\\033[31m"


*** Test Cases ***
Example
      Log To Console    Today is ${DATE}  "\\033[31mRed Text\\033[0m"
      Log To Console  My name is ${status}   "\\033[31mRed Text\\033[0m"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I put colors in console output with Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652486/how-can-i-put-colors-in-console-output-with-robot-framework)

Comment: I Tried that but am not able to get that text in different color